# string reverse program in C

Tags: c, string, gcc

i have written a program to reverse a string.. But it is not working.. It is printing the same string which is scanned.. What is the problem with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *strrev(char *s)
{
        char *temp = s;
        char *result = s;
        char t;
        int l = 0, i;
        while (*temp) {
                l++;
                temp++;
        }
        temp--;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                t = *temp;
                *temp = *s;
                *s = t;
                s++;
                temp--;
        }
        return result;
}

int main()
{
        char *str;
        str = malloc(50);
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf("%s", str);
        printf("%s\n\n", strrev(str));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chris: It's probably a homework assignment.  What does `while (*temp)` mean?  Is that even legal?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I know, just pointing it out. Anyway, it goes until the character at that position is null (end of string).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If it was homework assignment in C++ (the tag was removed meanwhile), `std::reverse` would have been the only correct answer.

Comment: @JanHudec If it's an assignment for deciding whether OP can write a simple algorithm, and not a "there's an stdlib method for this"-question, then it wouldn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why comment on a programming language that you're not familiar with? Yes of course it is legal and its meaning is clear to any C programmer.

Comment: @JimBalter: Why wouldn't I ask a question about something I don't understand?  Isn't that why we're all here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
```

You're walking through the entire string, so you're reversing it *twice* - it won't be reversed after all. Walk only halfways:

```
for (i = 0; i < l / 2; i++)
```

Also, try using `int len = strlen()` instead of the while-not-end-of-string loop, if you're permitted to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You swap the string's content twice.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code ..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strrev(char *s)
{
     char *temp = s;
     char *result = s;
     char t;
     while (*temp)
          temp++;

     while (--temp != s)
     {
            t = *temp;
            *temp = *s;
            *s++ = t;
     }
     return result;
 }

 int main()
 {
      char *str;
      str = (char*)malloc(50);
      printf("Enter a string: ");
      scanf("%s", str);
      printf("%s\n\n", strrev(str));
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: This one is fine.. Thanks for your interest.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The logic is to swap characters from start upto first half with the characters from last of second half, i.e, upto len/2. Just modify your for loop as below & it will work fine for you
for (i = 0; i < l/2; i++) {

Comment: You can use same program to check for palindrome. Define a int flag = 0 then within for loop if(*s != *temp) flag = 1;  then outside loop if(flag == 0) then palindrome..!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>


int str_len (char *str)
{
   char *ptr = str;
    while (*str)
     str++;
   return str - ptr;
}

int main ()
{
  char *str;
  int length;
  str = (char*)malloc(50);
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf("%s", str);
  length = str_len(str) - 1;

  for (int i = length ; i >= 0 ; i--)
  printf ("%c", str[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code is not much preferred.. As you are just printing it in the reverse order.. Reversing a string is expected, not just printing it in the reverse order.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use this code to reverse the string
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char str2[100],str1[100];
    printf("enter teh string 1\n");
    gets(str1);
    n = strlen(str1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    str2[n-1-i]=str1[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n",str2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are reversing the string twice...so after come to middle of the string, you should terminate the loop that is your loop should be run for half of the string length that is l/2 (in this case). so your loop should be like

```
for(i = 0; i < i / 2; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

swapping the string content twice..

swapping it once will help..

```
for (i = 0; i < l/2; i++)
```